# Creating a test class for a Select Statement

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex, test-class

I was wondering if you could help me. I am strugging to create a test class for the code below. Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

```apex
public class MatchReadyImage {

   public Match_Day_Check_List__c obj {get; set; }


   public MatchReadyImage(){
      obj = [
         Select Id, Match_Day_Ready_Status__c
         From Match_Day_Check_List__c
         Where Name = 'Everton V West Ham United Goodison Park EPL 2013-05-12'
      ];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a test data which will be selected by your code, because the data from Org is not available in test context. After that you have to instantiate `MatchReadyImage` class and validate that `obj` has a correct value

```apex
@isTest
private class MatchReadyImageTest {

    @isTest
    private static void test1() {
        Match_Day_Check_List__c mdckl = new Match_Day_Check_List__c(
            name = 'Everton V West Ham United Goodison Park EPL 2013-05-12';
            // other required fields 
        );
        insert mdckl;
        // you can add assertions which you want 
        System.assert((new MatchReadyImage).obj != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  I am getting the error "unexpected token: ')' at line 13 column 46"

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused what's the real requirement of having this class. May be you have posted very short version of it. Anyway you can use below test class(untested) for this.

```
@isTest
private class TestMatchReadyImage {

    @isTest
    static testMethod void testConstructor() {
        Match_Day_Check_List__c mdckl = new Match_Day_Check_List__c()            
        mdckl.Name = 'Everton V West Ham United Goodison Park EPL 2013-05-12';
        // populate if any other fields you need to
        insert mdckl;

        // make assertions for the unit test
        System.assert((new MatchReadyImage()).obj != null);
    }
}
```